# Tuning parameters using inflection points

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter

Assume a Machine Learning model has one real hyper-parameter. In many cases the hyper-parameter is chosen to be value at which the curve of a validation measure (MSE,etc) with respect the hyper-parameter has an inflection point, see [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=cfNICAAAQBAJ&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=tuning%20parameters%20inflection%20point%20charu&source=bl&ots=05BfJCjka7&sig=8UuW9l33MVQcB_oEB9nSRE4GIew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13qn3vJLYAhWs6IMKHWyDApEQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=tuning%20parameters%20inflection%20point%20charu&f=false) for a discussion.

Is there any mathematical intuition behind this turning method?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no statistics-based justification behind choosing the inflection point (the "elbow method"), but a similar criterion called the gap statistic can be derived mathematically: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf. The gap statistic is derived from the fact that if the data is actually distributed in $K$ clusters, then $K$ is an inflection point in the value of the weighted sum of the sums of intra-cluster squared distances.